# Next.js and Tailwind object-cover not cropping image and rounded does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, image, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js site with Tailwind and I am creating cards to display a few projects. Since the images are not the same size, I am trying to align them so that all the cards look the same.

Also apologize for any bad CSS as this is my first project.

Problem:

1. I tried using `object-cover` but the `Image` is spilling over the `div`.
2. The corners at the top of the card and the bottom of the `Image` are not being rounded for some reason. I used `rounded-t-2xl rounded-b-md`

Here is the code for the card component:

```
return (
    <div className="bg-cyan-50 rounded-2xl basis-1/3 shadow-lg flex flex-col">
      <div className="h-60 object-cover rounded-t-2xl rounded-b-md ">
        <Image
          src={image}
          alt={imageAlt}
          className="m-auto object-cover"
        ></Image>
      </div>
      <div className="px-6 pb-6 pt-6 flex flex-col flex-1">
        <h1 className="text-5xl mb-4">{name}</h1>
        <p className="mb-8">{description}</p>
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center mt-auto">
          <Link href={link}>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="bg-cyan-500 py-2 px-4 text-xl text-white rounded-xl hover:bg-cyan-600 shadow-lg inline-block"
            >
              {buttonText}
            </button>
          </Link>
          <div className="float-right">{children}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

The results are below. The `Image` is spilling past the `div` and the corners aren't being rounded for some reason.
[image: Images are not being cut off and are spilling over. Also the corners are not being rounded]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS for the image container, `div`.

```js
<div className="h-60 object-cover rounded-t-2xl rounded-b-md overflow-hidden">
```

This will make the border look rounded

Add the following CSS for the `image` tag

```js
<Image
  src={image}
  alt={imageAlt}
  className="m-auto w-full h-full object-cover"
></Image>
```

this will resize the image to fit the size of the parent element